# How to prevent that a JQuery button submit my form?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, jquery-events

I am absolutly new in JQuery development and I have the following problem.

I have a form that contains this JQuery button:

```
<!-- RESET BUTTON: -->
<td>
    <button class="resetButton" name="submitReset" onclick="return resetSearch(); return false;">Reset</button>
</td>
```

Clicking this button the user reset to null two input that are into my form performing this JavaScript function:

```
function resetSearch() {
    var f = document.getElementById('dataDaAForm');
    f.dataDa.value = null;
    f.dataA.value = null;
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

The script is performed but the problem is that after that it go out from the previous function the form is submitted anyway and I don't want that this behavior happen.

How can I prevent that the form is submitted when the user click on the **reset button**? As you can see I also try to add this statment but it don't work:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Another question is: is it the correct way to reset the values of the input tag of my form?

Comment: This is plain old vanilla javascript... no jQuery to be seen...

Comment: There is a javascript function that resets the form: `f.reset()`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
var form = $('#dataDaAForm')

$(".resetButton").on("click",function(e) {
    form.reset()
    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation()
})
```

Comment: This works, but it should not be the (best) answer. For example when the reset button's parent is not the form it won't work

Comment: Now it will work regardless of button's position, additionaly pre-caching the form element makes it more efficient rather than making a query on each click

Answer (score 4):

Give this a shot - you need to pass the event into the function. In addition, I've removed the need for inline JS.

```
$(".resetButton").click(function(e) {
    var f = document.getElementById('dataDaAForm');
    f.dataDa.value = null;
    f.dataA.value = null;
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

In addition to preventing the default, Javascript provides a method to reset your form:

```
$(".resetButton").click(function(e) {
    document.getElementById("dataDaAForm").reset();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

*Note: You tagged jquery, so I provided a jquery solution (although there is no jquery in your question).*

Comment: If you add the answer to his other question: "is it the correct way to reset the values of the input tag of my form?" then this is the best answer

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to create a reset button is an input type reset:

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset" />
```

Though if you really want to do it in javascript, the answer of James Hill will suffice